# Sybase add column

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I am trying to add column with text datatype with below query in Sybase

```
Alter table table-name
Add column-name text NULL
```

it throws error : row size could exceed row size limit, which is 1964 bytes

Please suggest appropriate query

Comment: Is this an _error_ or just a _warning_?  From [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23473710/Need-to-understand-the-Warning-Row-size-2494-bytes-could-exceed-row-size-limit-which-is-1964-bytes.html) it appears that this may just be a warning that you _could_ exceed the space for a row, were you to cram a ton of data into each text column.

Comment: It is an error. Actually I want to store string of variable length so want to use longvarchar or text datatype

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a warning: Did you check the table after running the command?What makes you say it is an error?

Comment: Couple of times I checked table but there was no entry

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following with no errors or warning, and the text field was appended to the table as expected:

```
create table hello (id int)

Alter table hello
Add stuff text NULL
```

What version of Sybase are you running?  My

```
select @@version
```

Shows

```
Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 27352 SMP SP139 /P/RS6000/AIX 6.1/ase157sp138x/4041/64-bit/FBO/Tue Aug  8 05:22:04 2017
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant for that to be a comment - I realize it's not the answer to your question :-).

Comment: You can always delete your answer and make it a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now.  However, when I tried to delete it wouldn't let me post a comment - so I elected to undelete rather than be too repetitious :-)